# Bootstrap error alert using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display error alert messages using bootstrap alerts. If a user submits the form with some fields empty, an error should be displayed. However when i click submit nothing is displayed.

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form[name="register"]').on("submit", function (e) {
    var email = $(this).find('input[name="email"]');
        if ($.trim(email.val()) === "") {
        e.preventDefault();    
        $("#errorAlert").slideDown(400);  
    } else {

             $("#errorAlert").slideUp(400, function () {     
            email.val("");    
        });
    }
});

$(".alert").find(".close").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();   
    e.preventDefault();    
    $(this).closest(".alert").slideUp(400);  
     });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="alert hide" id="errorAlert">
<a class="close">×</a>
Oops!!. You may have left some fields empty. Please fill them out.
</div>
<form name="register" action="" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="email" />
     <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

When i remove the "hide" class from the div above, the alert message comes up even before the form is submitted. If i then close the alert and submit the form, the alert isn't displayed. How do i get it working. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your `$("#errorAlert").slideDown(400)`, add `.removeClass('hide')`

that would be `$("#errorAlert").hide().slideDown(400).removeClass('hide')`.

I'm suspecting `hide` class has `display:none!important`. so we have to remove the class.

[DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/6W5gS/)

Comment: @Reigel you would also need to add the class back on $(".close).click().

Comment: @CameronW. no need... cause it will hide on `.slideUp(400)`

Comment: @Regiel touché. Ignore me - it's still early!

Comment: @ss_millionaire added a demo link... ;)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: http://jsfiddle.net/crw4K/

EDIT: Changing my answer because I haven't had my coffee yet.

Okay, so my changes to your code:

I removed the class 'hide' from the alert div, and added an inline style tag with 'display:none;'

Also, I removed the initial

```
$(".alert").find(".close")...
```

and changed it to just

```
$(".close").on("click"...
```

EDIT: I think I have found your problem. The .hide class in bootstrap is:

```
display:none !important;
```

which means it takes top priority over every other css for the element. Meaning that when you do slide down, the display:none !important is still taking priority.

You could either remove the class entirely, and add your own inline style tag (as I have in my answer) or you could remove the class with jquery.

Comment: i don't know the issue but my code isn't working even these changes

Comment: changed my answer, try again?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/VzVy6/79/)**</kbd>

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Run this code only when the DOM (all elements) are ready

    $('form[name="register"]').on("submit", function (e) {
        // Find all <form>s with the name "register", and bind a "submit" event handler

        // Find the <input /> element with the name "username"
        var email = $(this).find('input[name="email"]');
        if ($.trim(email.val()) === "") {
            // If its value is empty
            e.preventDefault(); // Stop the form from submitting
            $("#errorAlert").slideDown(400); // Show the Alert
        } else {
            e.preventDefault(); // Not needed, just for demonstration
            $("#errorAlert").slideUp(400, function () { // Hide the Alert (if visible)
                alert("Would be submitting form"); // Not needed, just for demonstration
                username.val(""); // Not needed, just for demonstration
            });
        }
    });

    $(".alert").find(".close").on("click", function (e) {
        // Find all elements with the "alert" class, get all descendant elements with the class "close", and bind a "click" event handler
        e.stopPropagation(); // Don't allow the click to bubble up the DOM
        e.preventDefault(); // Don't let any default functionality occur (in case it's a link)
        $(this).closest(".alert").slideUp(400); // Hide this specific Alert
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem's pretty simple. `.hide` is not a good idea to use here because it contains `display: none` with `!important` following it, so even when you are trying to display the alert, this property overrides it.

You could create a simple css:

```
.hid{
  display:none;
}
```

Add the `hid` as class to the alert box instead of `hide`.

**[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/wImLxUNHmO)**

Answer (score 0):

You could simply delete the `hide` class and add `style="display:none;"` to the `$('#errorAlert')` element. This way, the element will not appear on page load, and jQuery will manipulate the `display` property when using `slide*` functions. (it would never delete/add Bootstrap's `hide` class.)

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X2B9h/